# How to deploy sharepoint 2019 project that uses system.text.json to an on premise instance?

Tags: c#, .net, sharepoint

I've deployed a .net 4.7.2 sharepoint project (wsp) to an on prem instance of sharepoint.  I've added system.text.json nuget package 5.0.0.2.  The deployment does work great and appears in the central administration.  however, whenever a method is called that utilises system.text.json an exception is raised, could not find the library.

I've added the dependentassembly to the web.config with the correct version. but still the exception is raised.  Can anyone shed any light on what I've missed during deployment?

Comment: this is the exception: 

Could not load file or assembly 'System.Text.Json, Version=5.0.0.2, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have another option that will make all steps that you did automatically, adding the referenced .DLL into `Package.package`:

1. At Visual Studio farm solution project, go to `Solution Explorer`;
2. Click twice on `Package.package`;
3. Go to `Advanced` Tab;
4. Click in `Add` and select `Existing assembly`;
5. Select the `System.Text.Json.dll` from package subfolder into solution folder;

It´s another way that more easy, if you need to reference other externals references into your Farm Solution Project.

Comment: Ok cool, thanks Antonio I'll give that a go.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing the relevant assemblies into the GAC to solve the problem.  Once the correct versions were mentioned in the web.config, all began to work great.